# Spring boot file multipart accept half allowed size

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, file-upload, multipartfile

I wrote a controller as below:

```
@PostMapping(value="/upload", produces = "application/json")
@ApiOperation("Upload")
@ApiIgnore
public ResponseEntity<ResponseObject> fileUpload(
        @RequestParam(value="file") MultipartFile file,
        @RequestParam (value="code",required=false, defaultValue="0")String code,
        @RequestParam (value="approvaldetails",required=false, defaultValue="0") String approvalDeatils) throws Exception{
    return uploadService.uploader(file,code,approvalDeatils);
}
```

and I configured below at application.porperties:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=30MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=30MB
```

but I could able to upload file up to ~15MB
Editted:
Spring boot version: 2.0.1

Answer (score 1):

*****1. First potential cause:*****

Maybe it's related to the **spring-boot** version you are using.

MULTIPART properties have been changed according to versions.

Spring Boot 1.3.x and earlier

```
multipart.max-file-size
multipart.max-request-size
```

After Spring Boot 1.3.x:

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=-1
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=-1
```

After Spring Boot 2.0:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=-1
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=-1
```

***2. Second potential cause:***

Your app didn't have enough **memory** to receive the file

***3. Third potential cause:***

If you are packaging as war and deploying on tomcat, make sure that tomcat allows a `maxPostSize` suitable for your use case.

*In conf\server.xml:*

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443"
                maxPostSize="67589953" />
```

Answer (score 0):

@M.Mas.
1.I'm using spring boot 2.0.1.
2.Not depends on memory even if I decrease to 8MB, again ~4MB will be acceptable.
3. It is not deployed on the WAR file and I'm debugging.
I uploaded a file with 16.8MB and it raised below exception:

> org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (**33542171**) exceeds the configured maximum (31457280)

Comment: Add   server.tomcat.max-http-post-size=30MB to you property file.

Comment: @M.Mas. I added, nothing changed.

Comment: Are you sure that your file  size is lower than 30MB. From The exception your file higher than 30MB?

Comment: @M.Mas. Yes, for example I have a 16.8 MB file that not allowed with 30MB limitation! the file type is CSV.